# how to use sql query in android sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I am fairly new to sqlite database in android. I have a method that I should query a table in the database and return rows with a column value similar to its paramater.
In short I mean something like this:

```
Select * from TABLE_SHARES where KEY_NAME= sharename.
```

Here is my implementation of the method:

```
    public Cursor compare(String sharename) {
        Cursor cursor;
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = database.query(TABLE_SHARES, new String[] { KEY_PRICE },
                KEY_NAME + "=?", new String[] { sharename }, null, null, null,
                null);
        return cursor;
    }
```

However the cursor doesn't return any row despite there being matching rows. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Move the cursor to the 1st position and check if it returns something http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst%28%29

Comment: What do you mean with "similar"?